# What is the easiest way to synchronise model changes? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

We have two models that have the same fields **I know that it's not the best DB design** however it's been setup this way and that's it's being here for awhile.

---

Models: `User` and `Stakeholder`

Common attributes: `first_name` and `last_name`

Relationship: `Stakeholder` belongs_to `User`, and `User has_many :stakeholders`

---

So I'm looking to `listen` on any changes in User model and Stakeholder model that have similar attributes `first_name` and `last_name`

Few things that I have looked at:

```
=> after_save
=> Observer class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Observers have been removed in rails 4](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/6/25/Rails-4-0-final/).
Knowing this, you shouldn't design anything new using Observers.

The `after_save` callback seems therefore to be the best solution.

However, if you have this possibility, I would recommand a refactoring, to stop having this duplication of data.

Remove the `first_name` and `last_name` fields in the `Stakeholder` model.
And delegate these values to the user.

```
class Stakeholder < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :first_name, to: :user
  delegate :last_name,  to: :user
end
```

This way, you can do `Stakeholder.new.first_name`, and this will use the `first_name` method in the user relation.

You can delegate the `=` methods the same way.

```
class Stakeholder < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :first_name=, to: :user
  delegate :last_name=,  to: :user
end
```

And doing `Stakeholder.new.first_name = 'John'` will change the value in the user model.
It won't work with `update_attributes` though.

Comment: Using `after_commit` may be preferable since the callback is not called before the db transaction is committed. In cases with database constraints firing, `after_save` will be called for a record that is not going to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can implement after_save hook to listen on any changes in User and Stakeholder model.

As you have maintained the relationship between User and Stakeholder, you can retrieve first_name and last_name from User table for particular Stakeholder record. Why you are keeping them twice as same values for fields first_name and last_name you want to store?